# convert hindi into JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE+iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I had `document file` which have `hindi` words written in `hindi` font:- `Kruti Dev 010`
Now i want to enter these hindi words into the sqlite so that the screen get output format in `hindi`.
I know that i can do this with :`-JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`.
But how do i convert the `hindi` words into `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. and then save it into the `sqlite` database.
Please help me.

Comment: Have you find any solution ? If your answer is "yes" then put the solution here, that may help someone...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is i had created 1 doc file with the font:-Kruti Dev 010
And then copy pasted in sqlite.
In sqlite manager its showing in some UINOCDE.but when you make the query you convert the UNICODE into NSDATA and then into NSSTRING which will allow the user to write in hindi font in ios application.